# Draw lines between circles css

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm trying to draw lines between circles, i have this code https://codepen.io/cfmorales/pen/qBEqGpr, in some way it works but when you resize the page the height of the line doesnt match to the circle, any ideas of how can i make it responsive? all the magic is in the :before

```css
td:nth-child(2) {
            vertical-align: baseline;
          }

          td:nth-child(1) {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-right: 28px;
            width: 42px;
            height: 42px;
            border: 1px solid #999999;
            border-radius: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 31%;
            position: relative;
          }
          tr > td:first-child:before { 
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            background: #BFBFBF;
            height: 26px;
            width: 1px;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        
          }
          tr:last-child > td:first-child:before {
            display: none;
     
          }

          span {
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: #999999;
            font-family: "Playfair Display";
            font-size: 24px;
            line-height: 32px;
            text-align: center;
          }
```

```html
<table class="table_1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>1</span></td>
      <td><span>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>2</span></td>
      <td><span>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal mLorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>3</span></td>
      <td><span>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>4</span></td>
      <td><span>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>5</span></td>
      <td><span>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Those code doesn't actually work. Could you go into some more detail by what you are trying to accomplish? broken code isn't a good example of desired behavior as it is... well... broken.

Comment: First thing I see is that you are using a `//` comment in CSS. You can use those comments in a preprocessor like Sass, but native CSS only has one comment style: `/* comment */`. A `//` will cause problems. That line is breaking the whole thing and no one can see anything when they open your example. Go in and change that comment style and resave.

Comment: Do you just want the lines in to stay in between the circles, touching the circles edge, or to be going through the center of all the circles?

Comment: Srry guys its edited, @StephenMIrving i just want to connect the circles with the lines, and it has to be responsive

Comment: Does it have to be a table? What I see is a div with a left border and a ::before element with a number inside.

Answer (score 0):

**update**:

```css
td:nth-child(2) {
            vertical-align: baseline;
          }

          td:nth-child(1) {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-right: 28px;
            width: 42px;
            height: 42px;
            border: 1px solid #999999;
            border-radius: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 31%;
            position: relative;
            background: #fff;
          }
          tr > td:first-child:before { 
  
        
          }
          tr:last-child > td:first-child:before {
            display: none;
     
          }

          span {
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: #999999;
            font-family: "Playfair Display";
            font-size: 24px;
            line-height: 32px;
            text-align: center;
          }
.cc{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
.cc:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
background:
#BFBFBF;
height: 100%;
width: 1px;
top: 3px;
left: -55px;
transform: translateX(-50%);
display: block;
z-index: -1;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.num{
   position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<table class="table_1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="num">1</span></td>
      <td><span class="cc">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="num">2</span></td>
      <td><span class="cc">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal mLorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="num">3</span></td>
      <td><span class="cc">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="num">4</span></td>
      <td><span class="cc">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="num">5</span></td>
      <td><span class="">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
```

Comment: It doesnt work if u have text in it, check the edit

Comment: https://codepen.io/shahry4r/pen/gObLNbq check this, answer was updated too

Answer (score 0):

Better u can use SVG, check the below link

```
    <svg>
  <line
x1="50"
y1="100"
x2="500"
y2="100"
style="stroke:rgb(0, 0, 0);stroke-width:2.5"
/><svg>
```

Comment: where should i put that? after td's?

Comment: These are known as SVG  this is alternative for the previous method...using this you can easily draw lines circles...everything

Answer (score 0):

So I made a few changes to your code and worked on it a bit in my own Codepen. It is a tricky issue with the way you've formatted your markup with a table to have the line only go to the edge of the circle. What I did instead is give the circles a light color and send the line all the way down through all of them, but changed the z-index so it is hidden behind the color of the circles. I also added a wrapper `div` around the table itself to keep the line from continuing down to the bottom of the screen since I changed the height from `100%` to `90vh`. Only issue left to solve is getting the line to stop at the last circle instead of continuing on to the bottom of the last bit of text for the last circle. Regardless, it looks quite a bit better now than your original example in my opinion. I'm still working on it but you can check out what I've done so far here: https://codepen.io/stephenirving/pen/Jjobqrb

If you need me to explain any of my changes I would be happy to.

Current CSS code is here:

```
td:first-child {
    align-items: center;
    background: #add8e6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display: flex;
    height: 42px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 28px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 42px;
}

tr:not(:last-child) > td:first-child:before {
    background: #bfbfbf;
    content: "";
    height: 90vh;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 1px;
    z-index: -1;
}

td:last-child {
  text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: top;
}

tr:not(:last-child) > td:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

span {
    color: #999;
    font: 1.5rem/1.333 "Playfair Display", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapper--table-list {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 95%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced your table with divs.

I did some CSS magic here.

- The line is just a border-left.
- The circle is a ::before pseudo-element.
- Each ::before element has a counter in it.
- I also used CSS variables so it's easier to update several elements.
- I guessed that you didn't want the last element to have a line, so I used :not(:last-child) to stop that from happening.

```css
:root {
  --circle-size: 42px;
  --spacing: 28px;
  --text-color: #999;
}

.container {
  counter-reset: section;
  padding-top: var(--spacing);
  padding-left: var(--spacing);
}

.container > div {
  position: relative;
  padding: calc(2 * var(--spacing));
  padding-top: 0px;
  
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: "Playfair Display";
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.container > div:not(:last-child) {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.container > div::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: -4px;

  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
  width: var(--circle-size);
  height: var(--circle-size);
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  border: 1px solid var(--text-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal mLorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</div>
  <div>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal m</div>
</div>
```