# Automatic numbers for sections of a presentation

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I have a Reveal.js presentation with Markdown sources, structured as sections:

```html
<div class="reveal">
  <div class="slides">
    <section id="section1"
      data-markdown="section1.md">
    </section>
    <section id="section2"
      data-markdown="section2.md">
    </section>
    <!-- more sections... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Each section is made as a Markdown file (using the "vertical slides" feature). I want to display a section number on each slide for easier navigation. Currently I hardcode the same section number across each Markdown file:

```
<div class="eyebrow">Section 1</div>

# History
... as many "Section 1" as many vertical slides I have ...
```

Instead I would like to declare a variable `section` in the beginning of each Markdown file representing a section, and then reference this variable in the rest of the file. Pseudocode:

```
section=1
<div class="eyebrow">Section $section</div>

# History
... and so on, through the file ...
```

How to do this?

Comment: I would use CSS `counter` and display the numbers with pseudo-elements, just like I did in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59413479/5526624

Comment: I did the following, but it did not work. In the file with CSS theme css/theme/source/theme.css I added the following: 

.reveal .eyebrow > div::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(section) ": ";
}

Answer (score 1):

Use the pseudo-element `::before` to display a number, just like a list, and reset the counter with `counter-reset`.

```css
.slides {
  counter-reset: section;
}

section::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section)".";
}

section {
  /* JUST SOME STYLING TO MAKE UP FOR THE LACK OF CONTENT */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="reveal">
  <div class="slides">
    <section id="section1"
      data-markdown="section1.md">
    </section>
    <section id="section2"
      data-markdown="section2.md">
    </section>
    <section id="section3"
      data-markdown="section3.md">
    </section>
    <section id="section4"
      data-markdown="section4.md">
    </section>
    <section id="section5"
      data-markdown="section5.md">
    </section>
    <!-- more sections... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if `viewDistance` option is big enough to load the entire presentation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).