# Html drawing horizontal and vertical lines connecting circle nodes

Tags: html, css

I would like to draw the following in my web page:
[image]

where the three buttons are submit buttons.

I managed to do most but having a problem drawing the vertical lines.
here is my code:

```css
th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 50px 0;
}

span {
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
  border-right: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
}

.button_blue {
  background-color: LightSkyBlue;
}

.button_red {
  background-color: OrangeRed;
}

.button_yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.boxed {
  width: 600px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  font: bold;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <u style="color:Red;">
            <h1 style="color:DodgerBlue;font-size:3em;">
                Hashi
            </h1>
        </u>
  <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p></p>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <p></p>
      <table class="center">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style="border-bottom:4px solid black"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center"><text style="color:DodgerBlue;font-size: 2em;"> Build bridges </text></td>
          <td>
            <span> {{ form.create(class_="button button_blue") }} </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-decoration: line-through; text-decoration-thickness:5px;">
            <div class="circle" style="background-color:yellow;">
              3
            </div>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <div class="circle" style="background-color:OrangeRed;">
              2
            </div>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <div class="circle" style="background-color:lightgreen;">
              5
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>{{ form.load(class_="button button_red") }}</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="circle" style="background-color:blue;color:yellow;">
              4
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>{{ form.solve(class_="button button_yellow") }}</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: dont use a table if you not using tabular data. A SVG or pseudo-elements will help here.

Comment: Hi, could  I suggest that you recode in a slightly different way so that the structure will be more easily understood by  for example screen readers? The important bits are obviously the 3 buttons and they look a bit like a menu/nav or list, the large texts are probably headings and the circles/lines are decoration which can probably be done partly just by CSS and (as @tacoshy suggests) using pseudo elements.

Comment: @A Haworth, I already tried using decorations, but with no success. Can you show how? and yes the 3 buttons are a menu and the rest are decorations.

Comment: @tacoshy, an example will help

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use tables to do design, but if that's what you want, then I will come up with a solution for it.

1. Don't use inline styles. Refactor them to classes, so the HTML is readable.
2. Set `position: relative` on all TDs.
3. Place each element in a TD of its own.
4. Make the *circular* buttons `absolute` to position them on top of bottom right corner.
5. Use `colspan` to place the elements relative to each other.
6. Use `border` to draw the lines.

```css
/** UNCOMMENT TO REVEAL THE ENTIRE STRUCTURE OF THE TABLE **/
/*td { 
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
}*/

body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

h1 {
  color: DodgerBlue;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
  margin: 2rem auto 1rem;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

td.subtitle {
  color: DodgerBlue;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 1rem;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px none black;
}

td.right-line {
  border-right-style: solid;
}

td.bottom-line {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

td.double-stroke {
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button.big {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button.circle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.blue.big {
  background-color: LightSkyBlue;
}

.red {
  background-color: OrangeRed;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.lightgreen.circle {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.blue.circle {
  background-color: blue;
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
      <td class="bottom-line"><h1>Hashi</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="3" class="subtitle right-line">Build bridges</td>
      <td><button class="blue big">Create a Puzzle</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="yellow circle">3</button></td>
      <td class="bottom-line"><button class="red circle">2</button></td>
      <td class="bottom-line right-line" colspan="2"><button class="lightgreen circle">5</button></td>
      <td><button class="red big">Upload External</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="right-line double-stroke"><button class="blue circle">4</button></td>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><button class="yellow big">Run Internal</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Beautiful. I will implement it in my code. BTW, I don't have to use table, and I would like to see how it can be achieved without a table. Thanks

Comment: sorry to bother you again but your solution put the circle at the bottom of the cell, but the design have them at the center of the cell. So I guess I cannot use the border. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No worries. I did the table because it would only take me 20 minutes or so to come up with a proof of concent. You could go with pseudo-classes and relative distances, but that's a lot of work (about 2 hours?) for something that won't follow responsive design. The buttons on your image creates an unbalanced impression, but you could probably move them down with `transform: translateY`. That would, however, create a space between the horizontal top right stroke and the button. Anyways, I hope you manage to solve this issue.

Comment: You could probably look at an old post I wrote to get pointers of how to use pseudo-elements to "connect" circles with lines:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59413479/5526624